# Local IIS installation doesn't show phpinfo page

Tags: php, windows, iis

I've installed PHP on my windows 10 computer, and started IIS.

But when I browse to `http://localhost/phpinfo.hml` the page is completely blank.

And if I look at the file view in IIS, it seems that it's not aware that the file exists.

[image]

I've verified that the phpinfo.html file is in the right place:

```
 ls -l C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpinfo.html


    Directory: C:\inetpub\wwwroot


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         7/16/2020   8:54 AM             72 phpinfo.html
```

And has the right contents:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot> cat .\phpinfo.html
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

PHP is installed:

```
php --version
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 19:23:59) ( NTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

I gave my windows user full access to that directory. What am I doing wrong? How can I get this working?

Comment: Have you installed the php-extension for iis?

Comment: Nope, I have't. How do I do that?

Comment: where does your default website point to... post the main screen of IIS. PHP usage will come later to that (right now its not getting the HTML file even)

Comment: "PHP is installed". Probably not. The actual setup is much more complex, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: If I do `php --version` I get back a version number. I have that in the OP. Doesn't that mean that it's installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show phpinfo page, you need to change phpinfo.**html** to phpinfo.**php**.

And you also need to handle PHP requests by using IIS Manager, you can set this in Handler Mappings.

[image]

More information about how to configure IIS to Handle PHP Requests you can refer to this link: [Configure IIS to Handle PHP Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis#configure-iis-to-handle-php-requests)